# OpenMp set number of threads for parallel loop depending on variable

Tags: c++, openmp

Is there a way to set number of threads in OpenMP parallel for region based on the value of a variable? Initially for the whole application number of threads = nofCores. On my AMD FX 8350, nofCores =8. For this area if the variable is 3 then I only need 3 threads. If variable>cores then number of threads should remain equal to nofCores.

I do not want to set the number of threads globally for all the application. Just for this specific parallel loop.

Sorry if this is a naive question, but I am a newbie in OpenMP.

Comment: make sure to look into the documentation; it's not _that_ massive.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add this to your `omp parallel for` directive:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(variable)
for( ... )
```